# How do I create a Rails app with separate user accounts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails so I'm having trouble making an app with users. How would I go about doing this? Would I need to make a session controller separately for the users to log in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stay away from using Devise if you're new to Rails. In fact, this is what the Devise documentation has to say about it.

> If you are building your first Rails application, we recommend you to not use Devise. Devise requires a good understanding of the Rails Framework. In such cases, we advise you to start a simple authentication system from scratch, today we have two resources:
>
> Michael Hartl's online book: http://railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two#top
>
> Ryan Bates' Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch
>
> Once you have solidified your understanding of Rails and authentication mechanisms, we assure you Devise will be very pleasant to work with. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is to use a gem that takes care of that for you. The most popular is [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: Well for the app I'm building its a little more complicated than just registering with a username and password. Its for a game called league of legends and I'm using the developer's api to call their in game name. I'm trying to make is so that if you want to register to the app you will have to validate your in game username before even registering. Once you validated that the username your trying to register with is your in game name, it takes the in game name instead of a normal username. would Devise be able to handle this process? I'm sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: Devise is easily customizable, check the Configuring views/controller section of the readme for more info.

Answer (score 0):

there you can find the most popular gems for authentications: 
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication